# Is it right to using mongoDb with SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, mongodb

I'm developing BPM (business process management system) in ASP.NET with C# and Workflow Foundation 4.5.

BPM systems usually have a lot of process and each process has many forms. I made that easy by using JSON data so i will store all forms data in one table, so there is no need to create many tables for each process but this approach will effect the process searching service (advanced search for process business intelligence and business analysis), so I'm thinking to use MongoDb to store that Forms' data and search in it side by side with a SQL Server database to store everything else. Is that will be a good approach and practice?

Another question is using windows workflow foundation will be a good idea, I didn't see a lot of systems using it lately

Comment: for search you might as well consider https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch but fundamentally it's not a bad idea